# Excel macro help using a forloop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn macros in excel. I have the rougher edges worked out (inserting if statements and other equations into cells) and now I need help with loops. So I have a macro that will insert the following into a cell

Cells(2,31).Formula ="=if(istext(E2), ""Yes"", ""No"")

I need to basically insert this equation into 50 cells straight down so I would like to use a for loop to do this. Could anyone help with this, I can't seem to get it to work. The range should go from E2 to E50.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all the rows:

```
Dim row As Long
For row = 2 To 50
    Cells(row, 31).Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(E" & row & "), ""Yes"", ""No"")"
Next
```

But you can do this without a loop if you use a formula in R1C1 format, because the R1C1 formula is the same no matter which row you're on:

```
Range(Cells(2, 31), Cells(50, 31)).FormulaR1C1 _
        = "=IF(ISTEXT(RC5), ""Yes"", ""No"")"
```